# Excel - How to count cells depending on its color and the color of an adjacent cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm creating a calendar/schedule workbook in Excel. 
All week days are blue, weekend days are colored red.

One of the things I need to do is count how many weekdays (bue cells) a certain person works, but without fridays (also blue cells but above a red cell (saturday)).

Counting the total number of weekdays (blue cells) a person works is no problem:

```
 Function CountCcolor(range_data As Range, criteria1 As Range, criteria2 As Range) As Long
    Dim datax As Range
    Dim xcolor As Long
xcolor = criteria1.Interior.ColorIndex
radiologist = criteria2.Value
For Each datax In range_data
    If datax.Interior.ColorIndex = xcolor And datax.Value = radiologist Then CountCcolor = CountCcolor + 1
    End If
Next datax
End Function
```

This includes fridays though, which I don't want.

Is it possible to extend this code to exclude all blue cells which are exactly above a red cell?

Comment: Why not instead test the underlying date using Weekday() if it is a weekday or weekend.

Comment: If it has to be based on colours you could add an `and datax.offset(-1,0)<> ycolour` to your if statement to look at the cell above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Range.Offset property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060.aspx) to examine the cell directly below the one in the loop.

```
For Each datax In range_data
    If datax.Interior.ColorIndex = xcolor And _
       datax.OFFSET(1, 0).Interior.ColorIndex = xcolor And _
       datax.Value = radiologist Then
        CountCcolor = CountCcolor + 1
    End If
Next datax
```